# SSL error with cloudflare

Tags: php, ssl, dns, cloudflare

I'm trying to setup a ssl certificate with cloudflare. And it worked the first hour, but, after that, an error appeared and my website is not accessible in https anymore.
The error is :
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.leapride.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I don't really know how DNS works so could anyone maybe tell me where the problem could come from ?
Thanks

Comment: nobody could help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing some issues at the moment with your SSL certificates, two good online tools you can use to troubleshoot this are [digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/) and [Symantic SSL check](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp)

When checking, remember that www.leapride.com and leapride.com are considered to be different domains, so either check for both or make sure your server is redirecting from say no-www ==> www

**Update**

The SSL certs are validating well for me now. With web inspector I see an error now related to attempting to load http content on the https page, so good to fix this as well.

On your page, look for code being loaded from http://ipinfo.io

**Update 2**

If I check your SSL certificate chain in Chrome, or with [digicert.com](https://www.digicert.com/help/) I see **sni220092.cloudflaressl.com** , which is what I would expect. When I check with [Symantic](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) I see **ssl3.ovh.net** . It's odd that they don't match, not something I've come across before. Do you have any thoughts why we could be seeing this?

Good luck

Comment: I made the symantic SSL check, and here is the problem : "Please contact the Certificate Authority for further verification.
You have 1 error
Wrong certificate installed.
The domain name does not match the certificate common name or SAN." I sent an email to cloudflare but they don't answer :/

Comment: good going @FabulousCo , your SSL connection is working well for me know

Comment: And now it works again ! I don't understand want happens ^^

Comment: it has been stable for me the last 20 minutes, I'll watch it from time to time. If it settles down, maybe the  behaviour was related to caching or propagation

Comment: Yeah it's really weird, sometimes it work and sometimes there is a shutdown during a few hours...

Comment: Actually, my collegue changed the dns without telling me so it couldn't work properly --' Thank you very much for your help. I'm so sorry